# Python OpenCV threshold function produces the same result for different parameters

Tags: python, opencv, threshold

I had a grayscale image, whose pixels are float values from -1 to 1, which
I converted to `uint8` (0-255) with the `ConvertScaleAbs` function.

I want to threshold this image, but it doesn't work: the threshold result is the same with any limits (`Thresh` and `MaxValue`).  For example if they are 100-150 or 100-255, the result is the same.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import numpy

img = cv2.imread("C:\Python27\Archivos\Vinedo  Casablanca\Vuelo1\PythonOpencv\Seccion\Sin suelo\NDVI_hileras.tif", cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)

out = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img, alpha=(255.0/1.0))

rows,cols = out.shape
thresh = 104
maxValue = 120
th, mask= cv2.threshold(out, thresh, maxValue, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#threshold

Comment: More specific title. Clarify the problem as 1) What I have (a grayscale uint8 image), 2) What I want (threshold), and 3) What fails (same result always).

Comment: I was able to fixed it! I converted the image to HSV, so I used InRange function instead Threshold function.